# What is the most dangerous heresy that exists in the church today?

Tags: soteriology, acts, heresy, words-of-jesus, money

There are many heresies referenced in the New Testament and even more that have surfaced in the centuries since it was written. One is alluded to in the account of Simon Magus.

> 9Now there was a man named Simon, who formerly was practicing magic in
> the city and astonishing the people of Samaria, claiming to be someone
> great; 10and they all, from smallest to greatest, were giving
> attention to him, saying, “This man is what is called the Great Power
> of God.” 11And they were giving him attention because he had for a
> long time astonished them with his magic arts. 12But when they
> believed Philip preaching the good news about the kingdom of God and
> the name of Jesus Christ, they were being baptized, men and women
> alike. 13Even Simon himself believed; and after being baptized, he
> continued on with Philip, and as he observed signs and great miracles
> taking place, he was constantly amazed.
> 14Now when the apostles in Jerusalem heard that Samaria had received the word of God, they sent them Peter and John, 15who came
> down and prayed for them that they might receive the Holy Spirit.
> 16For He had not yet fallen upon any of them; they had simply been
> baptized in the name of the Lord Jesus. 17Then they began laying their
> hands on them, and they were receiving the Holy Spirit. 18Now when
> Simon saw that the Spirit was bestowed through the laying on of the
> apostles’ hands, he offered them money, 19saying, “Give this authority
> to me as well, so that everyone on whom I lay my hands may receive the
> Holy Spirit.” 20But Peter said to him, “May your silver perish with
> you, because you thought you could obtain the gift of God with money!
> 21“You have no part or portion in this matter, for your heart is not
> right before God. 22“Therefore repent of this wickedness of yours, and
> pray the Lord that, if possible, the intention of your heart may be
> forgiven you. 23“For I see that you are in the gall of bitterness and
> in the bondage of iniquity.” 24But Simon answered and said, “Pray to
> the Lord for me yourselves, so that nothing of what you have said may
> come upon me.”

Jesus clearly said that we cannot serve God and money and he cleansed the temple of money changers. The way money is handled in Christianity is the source of much confusion and heresy in the church today. Christianity can be a big and profitable business and many ministers acquire great wealth through it. Are there other heresies common in Christianity today that may affect people even more negatively than a money based heresy?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Martin. However, I fear this question may be closed as opinion based as well as not asking the perspective of a specific Christian denomination. Could you please edit your post to make it more on topic. This is a Q&A site and not a forum for conversation.

Comment: Everyone will have their opinion on 1) what heresy is most prevalent in our own generation (and therefore should draw attention as 'the most dangerous' 2) what constitutes 'heresy' in the first place 3) what makes a particular heresy 'dangerous'. I would say that the heresy of denying the eternal Sonship of the Lord Jesus Christ is very prevalent, yet not evident, little spoken of, deliberately tolerated and utterly destructive of true faith. But that is just my own opinion and is therefore a comment, not an answer. (And then we come on to the question of 'What, exactly, is 'the Church'. )

Comment: To more directly address the issues with this question... it is too broad and too subjective, and therefore not appropriate for this site. SE likes questions that can be *objectively* answered. If you were to ask what *a particular denomination* considers the most dangerous heresy, *that* might be acceptable. As stated, however, there are likely to be many different answers with no objective way to judge the "correctness" of any, which is why the question is problematic. As Ken said, "this is a Q&A site and not a forum for conversation".

Comment: By definition, this is not answerable by "all denominations" because many denominations effectively consider doctrines of other denominations heresy.

Comment: I repeat: *how do you qualify* "most dangerous"? If you can answer that in a way that isn't going to generate violent disagreement between different denominations, then *maybe* this is on topic. (BTW, "Are there other heresies common in Christianity today that may affect people even more negatively than a money based heresy?" is also definitely not on topic; questions asking for an open-ended list are not on topic on *any* SE, AFAIK.)

Comment: If you haven't read it yet, please read [What types of questions can I ask on this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071) Normally we would say that you need to scope this to a particular denomination, however I don't think doing even that would be enough. That's because Christians don't normally rank heresies: to the Trinitarian Christian denying the Trinity is just as fatal as denying the resurrection or denying that sin is a real concern.

Comment: According to your link, this is an overview question with a biblical basis and implications in theology and practice. "Overview questions are usually the hardest questions to answer, but they can also be the most informative. Unlike most questions here, they are not scoped to a single denomination, but instead inquire about all of Christianity." This is not about ranking heresies but about getting people's well-reasoned biblically based answers re what they judge to be the most important heresies. We could all benefit from learning what different traditions believe is dangerous for Xn faith.

Comment: @MartinHemsley because as I have already said, the concept cannot be defined universally and because this site is not a doctrine debating environment, it would be off-topic. The "most dangerous" heresy according to Lutheran doctrine may be very different than the most dangerous according to Baptist, Anglican, Catholic or Presbyterian doctrines.

Comment: The fact that so many on this site can't see the importance of the question I raised and what I'm trying to communicate about the methodology, giving more weight to minor procedural issues, shows me that my time is probably not well spent here. We should be discussing an issue here that is absolutely vital to our faith and walk with Christ.  We could be raising awareness to egregious error. We live in a world where censorship is increasingly restricting free speech and the pursuit of truth. Too many people are quiet and complicit when they should be standing up to do something about it.

Comment: @eques Where does it say a question has to be defined universally and how many questions here are? Just because a Baptist, a Catholic, and a Lutheran might have a different opinion about the most dangerous heresy, does that mean it can't be discussed here? How is talking about dangerous and false doctrine off-topic for Christianity? A wise person could learn from what all traditions have to say about this topic.

Comment: The site is what it is. It is a community with elected Moderators. And to avoid it becoming chaotic, there are rules. And it works, if one accepts the general limitations of communal websites.

Comment: You probably could ask this question of Catholicism since the modern popes have weighed in on it.   St. John Paul II said it was a "culture of death" and Pope Benedict XVI said "the dictatorship of relativism" and Pope Francis says it's climate change deniers, antivaxxers, Internet trolls and Trumpism.

Comment: It's not that we can't see the importance... it's that ***this is not a doctrine debating environment***. If you are looking to debate doctrine (which seems to be the case), then yes, your time is best spent elsewhere. This site is for questions that have at least some hope of being addressed without turning into a general melee. I agree with your points about censorship (an issue which YECs have known well for decades!), but when you say "we should be discussing", that right there is your problem. This is a Q&A site, not a forum for discussion. *Discussions* are discouraged here.

Comment: @MartinHemsley it is not that no one can learn from comparing the traditions, etc but rather that there cannot be a good answer that works in the Q&A format. If you allow as you would suggest, you risk votes being based upon denomination.

Comment: @Matthew Where do you see me asking for a debate here? I asked for people from whatever tradition to answer what is the most dangerous heresy for them. Several have done that here in this chat but it would have been helpful to see it elaborated with scripture for example.  I don't see how that is different from many of the question asked on the site and I see discussions everywhere here.

Comment: @eques Why not? Nigel could say, "I believe  the heresy of denying the eternal Sonship of the Lord Jesus Christ is the most dangerous one for this and that reason. He could cite historical precedents and passages like Col. 1:13-16 to support his view. Isn't that what people do here? Is this really about votes and how different denominations might vote? People aren't allowed to vote according to their denominational views here?

Comment: @MartinHemsley It becomes quite subjective because heresy can only really be defined relative to an orthodoxy. And yes, people are not supposed to just be voting based upon their denomination -- a Baptist shouldn't be up-voting answers that agree with Baptist understanding, but ones that answer the question best.

Comment: @eques So? You can give me one according to your orthodoxy, someone else will according to theirs. People will vote according to their beliefs which will usually be influenced by their denomination. You will tend to answer questions based on your Catholic beliefs. I was expecting people to answer this question based on their beliefs.

Comment: @MartinHemsley which is NOT what this site is for. It's not for duking out between denominations. There are probably other sites for that. The Q&A format works for things where there is an objective answer to a non-opinion-based question. answering relative to an individual's personal orthodoxy or voting on that grounds undermines the objective answer aspect.

Comment: @eques You keep exaggerating and misinterpreting my statements. Nearly every question is based on an opinion even if that opinion is not very clear or is in flux. You could answer my question objectively by saying for example, "I believe that the denial of the Trinity is the greatest heresy from my perspective due to the following reasons..." You can't control on what basis anyone might judge your answer or anyone else's anywhere on this site. How someone votes on an answer has no effect on its objectivity.

Comment: @MartinHemsley and you continual do not grasp the rules of the site. "From my perspective" is far more likely to be opinion-based than not. And you can't objectively compare different denominational frameworks in this context -- that's not say that there aren't objective criteria to evaluate doctrine only that it doesn't work within the structures of this site and its intended use.

Comment: I think we are going in circles here. *Everybody* has a perspective even if they are doing their best to answer objectively. I am not trying to compare any different denominational frameworks in any context subjectively or objectively. There is no logically justifiable reason to shut down this question by any published rules, but as Nigel said, "It is what it is" and you can do what you like here.  On a more positive note I will add that there are some good questions being asked and some good and/or thought provoking answers can be found here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128991/discussion-between-eques-and-martin-hemsley).

Comment: Thanks for the offer @equus. But what good what that do? It's probably best that we just let it go.

Answer (score 2):

Both in Biblical times and modern times, the two great dangers the Scripture warns against are idolatry (failing to recognize God as Creator and worthy of praise) and immorality (injustice against our fellow humans and disobedience to God) and the two are often linked. In Romans 1, we see that idolatry leads to immorality. Worshiping money is one example of idolatry that often leads to injustice.

The word heresy normally refers to false doctrine, whether that is a rejection of the Trinity or the deity of Jesus. While people on this site may disagree on what constitutes heresy, I think there would be widespread agreement that we are to avoid idolatry and immorality if we want to pursue devotion to Christ.

Comment: Hi @Zanarkand. I would agree with you to the extent that Idolatry is probably *the* fundamental sin. All denominations would probably agree with that. But it wouldn't fit the definition of heresy which is, to give one example, a doctrine or belief held to be true which in fact is false as conveyed in scripture.

Comment: Yes, I noted that in my response. But for a more specific response you will probably have to change your question a bit because different groups define heresy differently simply because they hold to different beliefs, as other commenters noted.

Comment: Right. But my point is that no denomination/Christian church would uphold idolatry, at least under that moniker, as a fundamental truth. They may very well practice it or even have it enshrined in doctrinal statements, and that could be labeled by other denominations or believers as heresy.

Comment: Interesting that you say *denial of trinity* is a heresy. I thought heresy was esteeming things *not* in the bible.

Comment: +1 for mentioning idolatry and immorality. "The word heresy normally refers to false doctrine, whether that is a rejection of the Trinity or the deity of Jesus." No, it doesn't. It refers to something at odds with standard belief. "opinion or doctrine at variance with the orthodox or accepted doctrine, especially of a church or religious system." from Dictionary.com. If you say heresy = false, then that doesn't say much since people disagree about what is true or false.

Comment: When someone calls something heresy they mean it denies a belief fundamental to their tradition, so from their perspective it is false. And one can make rational arguments about where those boundaries lie, so I don't think it is entirely subjective.

Comment: @user47952 - Paul (Titus 2:13) and Peter (2 Peter 1:1) both equate Jesus with God by use of the Granville-Sharp rule. Jude says there is one Lord, Jesus, who saved his people out of Egypt.

Comment: 'Widespread agreement' is not a gauge of 'dangerous heresy'. Would there not be 'widespread agreement' to continue this 'dangerous heresy' ?

Comment: Neither idolatry nor immorality per se are heresies. They are sins/evil, but not specifically heresy